# JNI to call .NET dll

Tags: java, c#, .net, dll, java-native-interface

I am trying to create a Java Application that will call C# dll through an intermediate Visula C++ dll, its all well and good when I try to run the .class file from cmd prompt or Eclipse IDE but the problem is in order to do it I need to place the C# dll in the same directory as the Java.exe or else there occurs an exception the the native call, thus making to impossible to build the Java Project, any idea as to how this can be done

Comment: Please clarify: what precisely do you mean by `"in the same directory as the Java.exe"`? Do you mean that you need to place the C# dll in the java bin directory where java.exe and javac.exe are located? If so, very strange indeed.

Comment: Yes it only seems to work when the C# dll is in the same directory as java.exe and javac.exe or else it gives some fatal error caused due to not finding the dll

Comment: And are you providing a decent classpath when calling your code?

Comment: Yup...it has no problem finding the vc++ dll that I am directly calling but even if the C# dll is in the same directory as the class along with the vc++ dll it still throws an exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable and register your managed (.NET) dll with COM Interop.
See this link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736

Answer (score 4):

There are other ways, without COM. You might find one preferable or need one if you can't change the .NET component to support COM clients.

When a process that loads the CLR, the assembly search paths are determined by the location of the process's main Win32 module. Assembly search paths are different than Win32 DLL search paths. In this case, it starts with the location of `java.exe`. As a result, the search paths include the Global Assembly Cache (GAC), the folder of `java.exe`, and  subfolders listed as assembly probing paths in `java.exe.config` (if it exists).

See [How the Runtime Locates Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

This leads to a few options:

1. Install the assembly in the GAC. (On an end-user machines an installer should be used but on a developer machine, you can use `gacutil`.)
2. Put the assembly in the `java.exe` folder. Or, conversely, put a copy of Java in your application folder.
3. Create a subfolder with write permissions for the assembly. Create or update a `java.exe.config` and list the subfolder as a probing path.
4. Create your own `java.exe` in C or C++ using the Java Invocation API. It's documented alongside JNI. You can name it whatever you wish since, after all, it is your application. (This what many Java-based applications do, even if they don't use .NET. For example, eclipse and LibreOffice.) The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html) gives a complete example in C. For a typical MSVC build, `jni.h` needs to on the project's include path, `jvm.lib` needs to be on the project's library path, and `jvm.dll` needs to be in the Win32 DLL search path.

Other alternatives:

1. The VC DLL can load the assembly explicitly from a path before the assembly is needed. See [Assembly::LoadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b61s44e8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1).
2. Load the assembly on demand after it's not found by the standard search. See [AppDomain::AssemblyResolve Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (but note it's description is wrong: failure has not occurred until and if your custom resolver(s) fails).

Comment: Care to explain the 4th point....it seems really interesting...I definitely wanna try it out