# Calling C# library from Java application: Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException

Tags: java, c#, java-native-interface, c++-cli

I have a simple C# class library, I wrapped it in a C++/CLI class library and loaded it into a simple Java console application. But when I run the Java application, I get the following error:

```sh
Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.

Process finished with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)
```

My C# library has a Class1.cs file:

```cs
using System;

namespace CSharpClassLibrary1
{
  public class Class1
  {
    public Class1() { }

    public void Print()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Hello World From C#!");
    }
  }
}
```

My C++/CLI wrapper has two files: HelloWorld.h and CppClassLibrary1.cpp.

HelloWorld.h:

```cpp
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class HelloWorld */

#ifndef _Included_HelloWorld
#define _Included_HelloWorld
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
  /*
   * Class:     HelloWorld
   * Method:    print
   * Signature: ()V
   */
  JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloWorld_print
  (JNIEnv*, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

I got it by running the command of the following form in my Java application: `javac -h <directory> -d <directory> <source files>`.

CppClassLibrary1.cpp:

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include "HelloWorld.h"

using namespace CSharpClassLibrary1;

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloWorld_print(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj)
{
  Class1^ cls = gcnew Class1();
  cls->Print();
}
```

I added the CSharpClassLibrary1 as reference to the C++/CLI wrapper.

I added to the "Include directories" setting the following paths:

```
C:\Users\ns16\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-C\ch-0\192.6817.14\jbr\include
C:\Users\ns16\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-C\ch-0\192.6817.14\jbr\include\win32
```

My Java application has a HelloWorld.java file:

```java
public class HelloWorld {

    public native void print();

    static {
        try {
            System.loadLibrary("CppClassLibrary1");
        } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
            System.err.println("Native code library failed to load.\n" + e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HelloWorld hw = new HelloWorld();
        hw.print();
    }
}
```

I specified the CppClassLibrary1 library path in the java.library.path variable.

Please help me! What am I doing wrong?

**Update**. A study of the problem showed the following:

1. In the Java application error appears in the `hw.print();` line. If you comment it out, the application will start successfully.
2. If in the C++/CLI wrapper in the CppClassLibrary1.cpp file you replace `Java_HelloWorld_print` function body to the `std::cout << "Hello World From C++/CLI!";` line, the Java application will start successfully and print the `Hello World From C++/CLI!` string.
3. If you create C# console application, add to it the C# library as references and add into `Main` method the `Class1 cls = new Class1(); cls.print();` code, the application will start successfully and print the `Hello World From C#!` string.

Comment: Which line does generate that `StackOverflowException`? Constructor or `print()` method?

Comment: @Slawomir Orlowski `print()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied the C# library assembly in the directory with the java.exe file (in my system it located in `C:\Users\ns16\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-C\ch-0\192.6817.14\jbr\bin`) and now the Java application works! I would not want to move the assembly out of the project directory, but this is the only solution I found.

Comment: I had the same problem and your solution of copying the DLLs to the Java bit directory solved my problem.
Did you find another solution to keep the DLLs in the project structure?

Comment: @RobertoVeraAlvarez see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24357747/7755085)